# Doubt in a differential equation (solution given)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Let $y=y(x)$ be the solution of the differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} x}+\frac{\sqrt{2} y}{2 \cos ^{4} x-\cos 2 x}=x \mathrm{e}^{\tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{2} \cot 2 x)}, 0<x<\pi / 2$ with $y\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{32} .$
> If $y\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{18} \mathrm{e}^{-\tan ^{-1}(\alpha)}$, then the value of $3 \alpha^{2}$ is equal to
>
> **Source** : Jee Main 2022 29th June shift 1

Now I  started off by simplifying the trigonometric expression(s) and then searching for the DE.

### Simplfying the DE

I simplified the trignometric term in the denominator by the following sequence of equalities:

$$ \begin{align}2(\cos x)^4 -\cos2x &=2(\cos x)^4 -2(\cos x)^2+1 \\  &= 1-2(\sin x)^2(\cos x)^2\\ &= 1-\frac{(\sin2x)^2}{2} \end{align}$$

My differential equation simplifies as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\sqrt{2}y}{1-\frac{(\sin2x)^2}{2}} =xe^{\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{2}\cot2x}}              $$

on further simplification I reached this

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{4\sqrt{2}y}{3+\cos4x} =xe\large^{\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{2}\cot2x}} $$

### Finding IF

We have by the standard formulas,

$$IF=  e^{\int\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3+cos4x}dx } $$ here I use substitution ( I have put $\tan2x=t$)
so that $ \frac{dt}{2(1+t^2)}$=dx and I wrote $\cos4x$ as $ \large \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)}$
Doing everything gives me IF as
$$IF= \huge e^{\tan^{-1}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})} $$ now t was tan2x so  my equation becomes (when we multiply IF on both sides of the equation)
$$\large d(y e^{\tan^{-1}(\frac{tan2x}{\sqrt{2}})})=xe^{\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{2}cot2x}+\tan^{-1}(\frac{tan2x}{\sqrt{2}})} dx $$
**now the solution given to me was that I should convert $\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{2}cot2x}+\tan^{-1}(\frac{tan2x}{\sqrt{2}})$ into $\frac{\pi}{2}$ I think that this step is wrong as this is only valid if x was in $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ as then $2x$ would be less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$**
We know that $\cot^{-1}{x}-\pi =\tan^{-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ when $x<0$ so we can't say that its pi/2 and integrate it. BTW if you assume it to be pi/2 the answer matches to what was given to me.

---

## Edit:

I think it should be like this:

$for0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$ $$\large y e^{\tan^{-1}(\frac{tan2x}{\sqrt{2}})}=\frac{x^2}{2} e^{\frac{\pi}{2}} +c$$ and $for\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\large y e^{\tan^{-1}(\frac{tan2x}{\sqrt{2}})}=\frac{x^2}{2} e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}} +c'$$

### Final conclusion :

Thanks to Mr IvanKaznacheyeu for pointing out that I only needed the second one of my 2 solutions for solving the problem. Here for completely solving the problem:
We consider 2nd part of my answer.
Here taking limits on both sides to solve for c'.
$$\large \lim\limits_{0\to \frac{\pi}{4}+} y e^{\tan^{-1}(\frac{tan2x}{\sqrt{2}})}=\lim\limits_{0\to \frac{\pi}{4}+}\frac{x^2}{2} e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}} +c'$$
solving the above will give c=0 and finally when we put x=pi/3 after some rearrangement this yields $\alpha$=($\sqrt\frac{2}{3}$) hence answer is 2

Comment: I was thinking of integrating it by breaking it into parts ie from 0 to pi/4 integration gives one solution and from pi/4 to pi/2 integration yields another solution

Comment: Note, that to answer the question you need only consider part from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/3$. If you want to find solution for all interval from 0 to $\pi/2$, you should write different $c$ for two parts.

Comment: $\arctan u+\arctan \frac{1}{u}=\frac{\pi}{2}{\rm sign} u$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yes thankyou corrected!! sorry for the late reply I was gone somewhere.

Comment: Source of the question ?

Comment: Jee main 2022(indian national college entrance exam)

Comment: Pl add that into the question with shift

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational Done

Comment: I can suggest you a site : https://mathpix.com/. In this you can put pic of the JEE Q and it will turn it into math jax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137948/discussion-between-beautifully-irrational-and-chemical-brewster).

Comment: I am very impressed at your presentation of the question since you have tried to explain your thinking. I think you wrote this on phone? I suggest you learn mathjax and write on computer... its much more simpler and the initial effort of learning pays off long term.